# Выполнение функции в определенное время

Tags: python, datetime, таймер

Как я могу выполнять **функцию каждый день в определенное время** (к примеру в 9:00, 13:15, 19:35)? Это нужно для моего бота во ВКонтакте. Условно, мне нужно выводить:

```
print("Hello world!")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Есть два варианта решения такой проблемы:

1. Ваша программа - обычное приложение, внутри которого выполняется вызов нужной функции. Тогда просто используйте *cron*.
2. Ваша программа круглосуточно висит в памяти (демон) и должна сама вызывать эту функцию. В этом случае проще всего использовать *sched.scheduler*. Можно посмотреть здесь: https://coderoad.ru/11523918/Python-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%83%D1%81%D0%BA-%D1%84%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8-%D0%B2-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D0%B2%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%8F